Backstage Gitlab discovery can't find repos in public gitlab
On Backstage, I am trying to fetch catalog-info.yaml files automatically for every project which belongs to a group of mine on Gitlab. I am using the GitLabDiscovery feature, but the logs are showing that there are 0 components found in 0 projects.
Here is my configuration:
app-config.yaml:
integrations:
  gitlab:
    - host: ${GIT_LAB_BASE_URL}
      token: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}
   
catalog:
  providers:
    gitlab:
      gitlab:
        host: ${GIT_LAB_BASE_URL}
        group: ${MY_GITLAB_GROUP}
        schedule:
          frequency: { minutes: 1 }
          timeout: { minutes: 3 }

GIT_LAB_BASE_URL = gitlab.com
MY_GITLAB_GROUP -> a group of mine with several projects that include catalog-info.yaml files.
index.ts
...
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend-module-gitlab/alpha'));
backend.start();


When using this setup (auth via integrations) I have had to grant maintainer permissions for the user who generated the token on all projects/groups I want Backstage to have visibility of.
You can get around this by registering Backstage as a GitLab Application:
https://gitlab.your-organization.net/admin/applications
You can learn more about this in the backstage docs here.

I only want to crawl components for a gitlab instance, not to allow users to authenticate using their gitlab acounts. Do i still need to configure gitlab OAuth? Or is registering backstage is enough?

With such a small crawl scope I'd be more inclined to simply give the person who generated the token maintainer access to the group where the projects live. As the scope grows over time, you can switch over to GitLab OAuth for a more seamless & maintenance free approach.

Unfortunately this is already the situation - I am using my personal user and trying to crawl only a group with projects the I created.

What logs are you seeing from backstage? What scope has the token got access to?

I found the issue - the projects I tried to crawl were shared with my group, but not actually under it's ownership. Once I created projects under the group with catalog-info.yaml files, it worked.
Also, crawling the gitlab.com hostname without group specification wouldn't work because it would crawl the whole instance which will never end.
